# Using React Native Background Fetch, how do I run only a headless task, and not the default task?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-background-fetch

As I've understood from the documentation, you initiate a default task (which runs when your app is minimized) and also optionally a headless task (which runs when your app is terminated). Like this:

```
//configure normal background task, set time interval as 15 minutes.
BackgroundFetch.configure({
  minimumFetchInterval: 15
}, async (taskId) => {
  console.log("[BackgroundFetch] taskId: ", taskId);

  // Finish, providing received taskId.
  BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId);
}, async (taskId) => {
  BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId);
});

let MyHeadlessTask = async (event) => {
  let taskId = event.taskId;
  let isTimeout = event.timeout;
  if (isTimeout) {
    BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId);
    return;
  }
  console.log('[BackgroundFetch HeadlessTask] start: ', taskId);

  // some task..

  BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId);
}

// Register your BackgroundFetch HeadlessTask, which also runs every 15 minutes, because of the above configuration of minimumFetchInterval.
BackgroundFetch.registerHeadlessTask(MyHeadlessTask);
```

What I want is to be able to register only a headless task, with the minimumFetchInterval configuration. Something like this:

```
BackgroundFetch.registerHeadlessTask(MyHeadlessTask, {
 minimumFetchInterval: 15
});
```

But I know `registerHeadlessTask` does not take configuration input. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: you can create a periodic task inside headless task before finish

Comment: How would that look like? Could you write a brief answer please?

Comment: I dont have any idea about react native but still I will try

Answer (score 1):

```
    let MyHeadlessTask = async (event) => {
      let taskId = event.taskId;
      let isTimeout = event.timeout;
      if (isTimeout) {
        BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId);
        return;
      }
      console.log('[BackgroundFetch HeadlessTask] start: ', taskId);
    ///// try this ////////
      BackgroundFetch.scheduleTask({
      taskId: yournewtaskid,
      forceAlarmManager: true,
      delay: 5000,
      periodic: true
    });

  BackgroundFetch.finish(headlesstaskId);
}
```

Now in your new task try doing work directly or maybe try creating headless task again there in which you do your work